# Using SQL CAST with the casting type retrieved from the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, sql-server-2012, varchar

Just wondering if this is even possible, and if so... how?

Table (**Foos**):

```
Column   Value
Id       int pk autoinc
Type     varchar(50) not null
Name     varchar(50) not null
Value    varchar(50)
```

When I do a `SELECT * FROM Foos` I get the following:

```
Id       Type          Name         Value
-------------------------------------------------
1        int           MaxScore     '100'
2        varchar(50)   Greeting     'hello world'
3        datetime      FollowupDate '01-01-2012'
```

I want to be able to create a SP that returns a record (using Id) and casting the record to the appropriate type before returning it. I know that I can easily just return the record as is and use an application to cast the string into the appropriate type... but I guess this is just to know if this is possible to expand knowledge and explore... something along the lines of:

```
SELECT Id, Name, CAST(Value AS [Type]) 
FROM Foos
```

But, I get the error:

> *Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Type Type is not a defined system type.*

Comment: I think this can be done using dynamic sql

Comment: how can a single column return multiple data types?

Comment: It probably could be done via dynamic SQL, but this always opens up the possibility of a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection_attack - eg. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @JW: Good point. I never thought about that... *sigh*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am sure you could do this using dynamic SQL, but I don't expect it would be particularly elegant.  Have you looked into storing values as [sql_variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, I have looked at sql_variant. I'm trying a range of different things to see what my best option is. So far I actually really like sql_variant because in my C# code it knows the underlying type. Not sure why everyone says to stay away from it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might give you what you deserve:

```
declare @Samples as Table ( Id Int Identity, Type VarChar(32), Name VarChar(32), Value VarChar(32) )
insert into @Samples ( Type, Name, Value ) values
  ( 'int',         'MaxScore',     '100' ),
  ( 'varchar(50)', 'Greeting',     'hello world' ),
  ( 'datetime',    'FollowupDate', '01-01-2012' ),
  ( 'money',       'PriceEach',    '99.4' )

select Id, Name, Type, Value, case
  when Type = 'DateTime' then Cast( Convert( DateTime, Value, 104 ) as SQL_Variant )
  when Type = 'Int' then Cast( Cast( Value as Int ) as SQL_Variant )
  when Type = 'Money' then Cast( Cast( Value as Money ) as SQL_Variant )
  when Type like 'VarChar(%)' then Cast( Cast( Value as VarChar(8000) ) as SQL_Variant )
  else NULL end Variant
  from @Samples
```

The `VarChar` case should have additional code to parse the length and use `SUBSTRING()` to return a suitable length.

May dog have mercy on your soul.

Comment: Seems like if I was to do that I might as well use sql_variant to begin with?